# Typescript this parameter type

Tags: typescript

```js
defineProperties(Element.prototype, {
    querySelector: {
        value: querySelectorPatched,
        writable: true,
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true,
    },
    querySelectorAll: {
        value(this: HTMLBodyElement): NodeListOf<Element> {
            const nodeList = arrayFromCollection(
                elementQuerySelectorAll.apply(this, ArraySlice.call(arguments) as [string])
            );

            if (!featureFlags.ENABLE_NODE_LIST_PATCH) {
                const filteredResults = getFilteredArrayOfNodes(
                    this,
                    nodeList,
                    ShadowDomSemantic.Disabled
                );
                return createStaticNodeList(filteredResults);
            }

            return createStaticNodeList(
                getFilteredArrayOfNodes(this, nodeList, ShadowDomSemantic.Enabled)
            );
        },
        writable: true,
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true,
    },

});
```

I want to understand this part of the following Typescript code here:

```
value(this: HTMLBodyElement): NodeListOf<Element>
```

I believe this code is overriding the standard `querySelectorAll` method. But the method is being defined on an `Element`, yet the value for `this` in the function is `HTMLBodyElement`. Does this mean the method can only be called from a `body` element? Or perhaps it's called from `Element` and then casted to `HTMLBodyElement`? Can someone explain the logic of this code? This is a part of the following [repository](https://github.com/salesforce/lwc/blob/master/packages/%40lwc/synthetic-shadow/src/faux-shadow/element.ts#L365).

Comment: I don't think it would make much of a difference to have it be an `HTMLElement`. Might have a few useful properties that a `HTMLElement` doesn't. `HTMLBodyElement` plays a more important role in the `getFilteredArrayOfNodes` function just above, where it is used to check if the node in question has the lwc patch enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody will explain this better than the developers of that project, but it totally looks like a mistake to me.

`this` is only being used in three function calls of two different types, in which it is passed as one parameter:

```
function querySelectorAll<E extends Element = Element>(selectors: string): NodeListOf<E>;

function getFilteredArrayOfNodes<T extends Node>(
    context: Element,
    unfilteredNodes: T[],
    shadowDomSemantic: ShadowDomSemantic
): T[]
```

When passing `this` typed as `HTMLBodyElement` to each of these functions, the type is actually always widened as `Element`, even in `querySelectorAll` because there is no type provided between angle brackets and no possible inference so the resolved `E` type is `Element` (the default type).

According to me, `value(this: HTMLBodyElement)` should be `value(this: Element)` because it is meant to override `Element.prototype.querySelectorAll`.

Doing so doesn't break anything in the code and is much more correct.

Comment: Can you show how this method would be called say from a non `body` element, say from `div`? And what would happen to `this` when method is called?

Comment: Well `this` is always typed as it is [declared](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#declaring-this-in-a-function) so whatever the actual element type is, the type of `this` is `HTMLBodyElement` in `value`. However it does not really matter because the type gets widened to the most generic type `Element` when being passed as a parameter to `querySelectorAll` and `getFilteredArrayOfNodes`. So as I said, no impact when changing `HTMLBodyElement` to `Element` like it should be. The code will just work as it did, it's just a matter of code clarity for the developers.

Comment: Where did you identify that the parameter is passed to these methods?

Comment: In the code `this` appears three times, always as a parameter of a function call